# Dissolve multiple layers

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I want to dissolve over 100 shapefiles into same attributes to eliminate number of features. I was going to merge all the polygon first then dissolve it, but each layer has 10,000 to over 50,000 features so it took too much time. I would like to know how to dissolve these layers or alternatively to merge them then dissolve without crashing QGIS everytime. I pasted a picture showing one layer that consists of small polygons as meshes. [image]

Comment: Shapefile has a 2 GB size limit and probably you must switch to some other format by the same.

Comment: With so much data it would be easier and probably faster to use PostGIS or spatialite.

Comment: Convert all shapefiles to geopackages then try merge and dissolve. You can execute "Convert format" with "Execute as batch process" for the conversion

Comment: Isn't this a task which can be done with Python, at least if you apply the same algorithms on each layer?